# The module was compiled against a different Node.js version using - elecntron nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to run node ibm_db library in my electron app. Since there are some problems with vue-electron-builder with the latest versions of node, I've installed as a dependency of my app node 16. The app will run without problems when I don't include the ibm_db library, but when I try to use it, I will have some trouble.

After cd into the ibm_db folder and run the command npm i, I've tried to do a test using the command node test/test-basic-test.js

```
Error: The module '\\?\C:\Users\...\Desktop\tool\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 108. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1243:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at bindings (C:\Users\bpaolillo\Desktop\RIFATTURAZIONE\node_modules\ibm_db\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bpaolillo\Desktop\RIFATTURAZIONE\node_modules\ibm_db\lib\odbc.js:57:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

How I can fix this issue to test the library and connection with db2?